# How to create a pdf from sqlite database and send in android java

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, itext

I am trying to create an invoicing system in android studio and I do not know how to get the data in the sqlite database, add them to a pdf then send the pdf via email. I have tried the tutorials that use Itextpdf but after adding the dependency as follows

```
     implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.11'
```

and trying to import the necessary classes, I am getting the error; can not resolve symbol text.
[image]
How could I go about creating the pdf and emailing?
Thanks

Comment: Classes `com.itextpdf.text.*` are iText 5, and you have added a dependency on iText 7. That's not going to work. Either you change your code to be iText 7 compatible, or you change your dependency to iText 5. Keep in mind that iText 5 is EOL and only gets security updates. And for Android you need a special version, iTextG. With iText 7 you can use the same version for plain Java and for Android.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse would you have a link to any resource that can help me do that?